# MYSQL getting error while using check for Date of birth

Tags: mysql

I am a very beginner in MySQL and I am trying to create my first table with MySQL with `CHECK` and I am having trouble. I did bunch of research but was not able to find anything. What I am trying to do is:

1. EmployeeId should be in format of `E###` (but when I enter `E1234`, the table is accepting the value) In reality it should not). It should only accept the value that starts with `e` and has only has 3 numbers after E.
2. The main problem I am facing is that to `CHECK DOB`. What I have to do is that I have to not accept the value of DOB that is less than 16 years and the has to enter the full date not the age. And I am having trouble in that.
   Any help would be appreciated. Here is code. Thanks in advance.

   ```
    CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeID varchar(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
       CHECK (EmployeeID REGEXP '^E[0-9]+$'),
    DOB date CHECK (DOB >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 16 YEAR),
    FirstName varchar(200),
    MiddleName varchar(200),
    LastName varchar(200),
    Address varchar(255),
    StartDate date,
    Gender varchar(100)
    );`
   ```

And the error I am getting is
`Error Code: 3814. An expression of a check constraint 'employee_chk_2' contains disallowed function: curdate.`

Comment: use a insert tigger

Comment: @nbk can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

[CHECK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) only accepts deterministic built-in functions, which `CURRENT_DATE` definitely isn't.

If `EmployeeID` only accepts 3 characters after `E` then the regex should be `'^E[0-9]{3}$` and the column should be `binary(4)`.

Comment: can you please help me with DOB?

Comment: you can't apply the check constraint on DOB like this because it contains CURRENT_DATE which changes every 24 hours. Maybe apply the ">= 16" years constraint logic in the application?

Comment: @danblack what should I do>

Answer (score 1):

As already said, Current_date is a non deterministic function and as such can't be used.

One possibility is to write a trigger before insert, and you need one for BEFORE UPDATE also

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_Employee_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON Employee FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.DOB >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 16 YEAR THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'employee is too young';
    END IF; 

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Employee (
>  EmployeeID binary(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>     CHECK (EmployeeID REGEXP '^E[0-9]{3}$'),
>  DOB date ,
>  FirstName varchar(200),
>  MiddleName varchar(200),
>  LastName varchar(200),
>  Address varchar(255),
>  StartDate date,
>  Gender varchar(100)
>  );`
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_Employee_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON Employee FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>
>     IF NEW.DOB >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 16 YEAR THEN
>         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'employee is too young';
>     END IF; 
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES('E001','2006-04-25','test','test','test','myqadress', Current_Date(),'male')
> ```
>
> ```
> employee is too young
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71cd8d74a319a0312ea40d01d40a1e74)*

Comment: where do i have to write this?

Comment: I don't know why fiddle is working and my workbench is not working

Comment: you start where you write my  create table and after you run it without errors you use the same window to run the create trigger with delimiter and please not working is not enough to help, we need the complete error message